# Equivalent of tuples in Dart

Tags: dart

As you know in typescript there is a type called tuple.
such as

```
type movieType= [string, number, Date];
let movieRating: movieType= ["Seven", 8.9, new Date(1996, 0, 5)];
```

How would you do that in Dart?

Is it like an Array marked as const

```
final movieRating = const ["Seven", 8.9, new Date(1996, 0, 5)];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That looks like a list to me in dart

Comment: Also, this is not something Dart supports today but the topic is still being discussed in the Dart language issue tracker: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/68 . For now, check the thread I linked to earlier for alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks @inigo
That package  tuple is a way to use it
   
   `import 'package:tuple/tuple.dart';
   void main(){
    final _joker1= Tuple3<String,int,DateTime>('Joker',10,new DateTime(2021,05,05));
    final _joker2= ()=>Tuple3.fromList(['Joker',10,new DateTime(2021,05,05)]);
    print(_joker1);
  }`